# How to prevent nested mapped elements from firing onClick event twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I created a quiz app and it has questions and options. First of all, I mapped the questions and inside that mapping, I mapped the options which belong to that question. Every option has its own onClick event handler for setting the answer and that event handler sends the answer to server. But the problem is that event handler sends request twice. The reason must be that elements created with nested mapping but I haven't found any solutions. 
Here is the part of the code:

```
let questions = null
if (this.props.questions) {
  questions = this.props.questions.map((question, index) => {
    return (
      <div className={classes.Question} key={question.id}>
        <p>{`${index + 1}) ` + question.value}</p>
        {question.options.map((option, optionIndex) => {
          return ( 
            <label onClick={question.clicked ? null : () => this.props.onSetQuestionAnswer(...params)} key={optionIndex}>{option.value}
              <input type="radio" name="radio" />
            </label>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Click event action creator

```
export const setOptionForQuestion = (...params) => {
    return async dispatch => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(`endpoint`, {
          ..body
        })
        if (data.success) {
          dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.SET_ANSWER_OPTION,
            ...dataToReduxStore
          })
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: actionTypes.SET_ANSWER_OPTION_ERROR
        })
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: you  didn't close the onClick={} ?

Comment: @RicardoCosta I missed it while refactoring the code for posting here. Problem is different

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, does it make 2 POST requests?

Comment: Yes. I thought it was because of nested maps but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: is it not one OPTION request and another POST? can you show your handler?

Comment: No, there happens to be 4 requests in total  with the option request. I added the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try by calling `event.preventDefault()`

```
export const setOptionForQuestion = (...params,e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    // rest of the code
  }
```

Comment: or stopPropagation

Comment: I did try this before but I'm pretty sure It didn't work. And now it works. Thank you!